# update table based on concatenated column value

Tags: oracle

I have a table with only 4 columns

First column - The concatenated column values for each row from another table.The columns are concatenated based on column id from the metadata table.The order of concatenation is the same order of column ids.
Second column -I have the comma separated primary key columns.
Now, based on the primary keys in the second column, I need to update the 3rd column which will retrieve the values for the primary key from each of the first concatenated field.

4 column _ it has the table name.

I am using cursor and string functions and it works perfectly fine but when I tested it fir huge millions of data , it failed and the performance is very  poor.

Could anyone give please me a single update query for the same

There is a comparison tool which compares the data between 2 tables in different database but with same data structure and it dumps the mismatch rows into a table with all the columns concatenated(pipe seperaed).The columns are in the same order as that of column id and I know the primary keys for that table(concatenated but pipe seperated). So, based on this data I need to extract the primary key values for which there is a data mismatch.

I need to do something like

Update column4(primary key values pipe seperated extracted from column2)

Comment: Please post table structures and data, existing code, requested output ...

Answer (score 0):

Check this [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78b4a/1), maybe will be useful. With that query you could concatenate a value with a character you need (this works for 11g2 version, for earlier versions use xmlagg 
, xmlelement, extract method).

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  FIELD INT);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(4);

SELECT listagg(FIELD,',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FIELD)
FROM TEST
```

Returns '1,2,3,4'